# How to do Taxes on Cryptocurrency Profits/Losses

Tags: united-states, taxes, cryptocurrency

I got into Cryptocurrency and was wondering how the taxes would be addressed on profits and losses of trading cross currency.

1. I have not converted my cryptocurrencies to any government backed fiat.
2. I have sustained large gains and large losses with ended up allowing me to only see a 10% gain over my initial investment.

If I take the cryptocurrencies and convert them to USD, would I be subject to long/short term capital gains?

FYI: This is for a personal hobby, not a business.

Comment: It seems likely that you will have to pay capital gains on cross-currency trades. The IRS does not require that things be cashed out to fiat currency to be taxable. Any trade of property is potentially taxable. There is a provision where "like-kind exchanges" may defer captial gains, however [it seems unlikely that the IRS will view cryptocurrency trades as like-kind exchanges](https://www.investopedia.com/news/how-new-tax-law-impacts-cryptocurrencies-trump/).

Comment: @mikez your linked quote isn't relevant until people are filing taxes early 2019.

Comment: @CQM I was specifically referring the treatment of crypto-currencies trades as property trades which are taxable. This has been [the IRS guidance since 2014](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-virtual-currency-guidance) and is unchanged by recent tax policy changes AFAIK. Other topics mentioned in that article like pass-through entity deductions are, of course, covered by that bill and not applicable to 2017 taxes.

Comment: @mikez the 2018 and onward tax law completes removes like-kind trades from the tax code, except for real estate. The IRS will never have to make a concrete decision on crypto-crypto trades anymore since they are all taxable now, it isn't worth their time to challenge 3 years of unclear guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Taxes would be applied the same way as gains/losses on stocks. As soon as you sell your cryptocurrency, it will become subject to capital gains/losses. Whether it is short term or long term depends on how long ago you bought them. If your marginal tax bracket is at 15% and you have held your cryptocurrency for over a year, you will owe nothing. Otherwise you can expect to pay about 15% on your gains (offset by your losses).

Comment: What would qualify as a sale ? Say for instance, If I buy BTC for $100 and it qrew for $110, then I use the BTC to buy $110 worth of ETH, am I making a sale here ? would this $10 be considered a profit, though I did not realize in FIAT currencies ?

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan yes, as of right now that is the case. If you take your crypto and buy *anything* with it, even other crypto, that is a sale. There has been talk of changing that in the future, but I wouldn't count on it.